# Edit summary for removal of 'thx' 'hi' etc

Tags: support

When removing things like 'thanks' and 'hello' and so-forth I have seen a specific term used to refer to these sorts of edit, but I can't recall what it is. Could people remind me of the word used for this type of edit?

Comment: I suppose. But I've seen another term which was just a single word. I just can't remember what it was.

Comment: Honestly, I never write explanations for that type of edit...

Comment: copy edited maybe?

Comment: It wasn't that. It was a single word, beginning with 'c' I think. Like 'removed c******'. (Apologies for the accidental inference of a rude word here).

Comment: Removed clutter.

Comment: You can use remove clutter too, I think. Personally I think I'll stick with chaff, though cruft was the word I remembered. You could always just go with: removed crap too, I suppose, though it might be seen as offensive to the user.

Comment: I simply copy this link into edit summary: [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @gnat Hhhhm. Seems like a lot of effort. Maybe when I'm hopped up on ng drink or something?

Comment: I use "fluff"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always said "removed **cruft**", but if you're looking for a single word, "concision" or "professionalism" ought to do it.

Comment: Cruft. That's the one I saw. Though I think 'removed chaff' would work too. 'Concision' or 'professionalism' also seem acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

[salutation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/salutation):

> a word or phrase serving as the prefatory greeting in a letter or speech, as Dear Sir in a letter or Ladies and Gentlemen in a speech.

See also: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

So, it should be "removing salutations".

Comment: Is 'thanks' a salutation?

Comment: @Peter as far as I know, yes. But I might be wrong. Worth taking a look on English.SE site and if not asked yet, ask there. :)

Comment: When my ban runs out I will. https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/salutation seems to be suggesting not, but there may be a way of making 'thanks' fit with this definition using some semantic trickery. It's plausible at least.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter for "thanks", etc. at the *end* of  the post, I usually say: "removed signature"

Answer (score 3):

I've been using "Blew away fluff" for a while now. Seems to do the job.

(Whether you read this as gently puffing at dandelion fluff, or ruthlessly gunning down the offending noise, is a matter of deliberate ambiguity.)

Comment: Am I allowed to just accept the answer that amused me most, even though another one was technically closer to what I was asking about?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter It's meta, you can kind of do what you like, although I wasn't really expecting the acceptance ;)

Comment: Hmmm. I shall alternate my validation back *does the validation dance and makes another little tick go green*

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Just so long as you mean [marshmallow cream](https://toughsledding.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/fluff.jpg) and not [cute](https://www.kibin.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/fluff.jpg) [animals](http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/i-am-the-almighty-so-fear-the-fluff.png).